# In pandas appear Wrong words

Tags: pandas

I have some datas.You can see him in the following.

```
     user_id  item_id cate_id action_type  action_time
0   11482147   492681    1_11        view   1487174400
1   12070750   457406    1_14   deep_view   1487174400
2   12431632   527476     1_1        view   1487174400
3   13397746   531771     1_6   deep_view   1487174400
4   13794253   510089    1_27   deep_view   1487174400
5   14378544   535335     1_6   deep_view   1487174400
6    1705634   535202    1_10        view   1487174400
7    6943823   478183     1_3   deep_view   1487174400
8    5902475   524378     1_6        view   1487174401
```

Then I write this code:print(w.groupby('user_id').size())

But the result don't I want.You can see him in the following.

```
077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795     67
08f6ea6d2181b902d8cbeccdccf61efc         34
095A18FB-2C8E-4C00-8F2D-B481CB674ECE      4
096F9140-F748-4DE3-A4C3-EBAAA277144D     64
0B9DDF98-12A0-45DF-9CF7-F4194BF23282     64
0F3D4D6F-A906-4396-BA3B-1E69B0F6867C      8
10000484                                 88
10000886                                105
10000953                                 51
10000956                                 41
10001967                                165
```

Why appear this case?

Answer (score 0):

If need convert index to column call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = w.groupby('user_id').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
    user_id  count
0   1705634      1
1   5902475      1
2   6943823      1
3  11482147      1
4  12070750      1
5  12431632      1
6  13397746      1
7  13794253      1
8  14378544      1
```

---

If call [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) output is [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), first column is `index`:

```
s = w.groupby('user_id').size()
print (s)
user_id
1705634     1
5902475     1
6943823     1
11482147    1
12070750    1
12431632    1
13397746    1
13794253    1
14378544    1
dtype: int64

print (type(s))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (s.index)
Int64Index([ 1705634,  5902475,  6943823, 11482147, 12070750, 12431632,
            13397746, 13794253, 14378544],
           dtype='int64', name='user_id')
```

But if think you get wrong values, you can also sort `DataFrame` by column `user_id` with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and check it, because `groupby` sorts group keys by default:

```
print (w.sort_values(['user_id']))
    user_id  item_id cate_id action_type  action_time
6   1705634   535202    1_10        view   1487174400
8   5902475   524378     1_6        view   1487174401
7   6943823   478183     1_3   deep_view   1487174400
0  11482147   492681    1_11        view   1487174400
1  12070750   457406    1_14   deep_view   1487174400
2  12431632   527476     1_1        view   1487174400
3  13397746   531771     1_6   deep_view   1487174400
4  13794253   510089    1_27   deep_view   1487174400
5  14378544   535335     1_6   deep_view   1487174400
```

EDIT:

For remove non numeric values with rows use:

```
#change first and last value to non numeric
print (w['user_id'])
0    0F3D4D6F-A906-4396-BA3B-1E69B0F6867C 
1                                 12070750
2                                 12431632
3                                 13397746
4                                 13794253
5                                 14378544
6                                  1705634
7                                  6943823
8     077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795
Name: user_id, dtype: object

w = w[pd.to_numeric(w['user_id'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
print (w)
    user_id  item_id cate_id action_type  action_time
1  12070750   457406    1_14   deep_view   1487174400
2  12431632   527476     1_1        view   1487174400
3  13397746   531771     1_6   deep_view   1487174400
4  13794253   510089    1_27   deep_view   1487174400
5  14378544   535335     1_6   deep_view   1487174400
6   1705634   535202    1_10        view   1487174400
7   6943823   478183     1_3   deep_view   1487174400
```

Explanation:

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering by mask created by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) (parameter `errors='coerce'` replace non numeric to `NaN`) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
print (pd.to_numeric(w['user_id'], errors='coerce'))
0           NaN
1    12070750.0
2    12431632.0
3    13397746.0
4    13794253.0
5    14378544.0
6     1705634.0
7     6943823.0
8           NaN
Name: user_id, dtype: float64
print (pd.to_numeric(w['user_id'], errors='coerce').notnull())
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
Name: user_id, dtype: boo
```

Comment: I can't understand why appear 077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795     67.I think it like this.for example 10000484                                 88

Comment: Because this values are in data, check last part of answer for check it. Myabe some wrong data I guess

Comment: In other words,I hope 077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795  is number..

Comment: So do you need remove all values wchi are not numeric?

Comment: no ,I want to convert str to int.but i'm failed.print(w['user_id'].apply(lambda x:int(x)))

Comment: Appear this problem.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A000004F540B15'

Comment: But it is impossible convert string like `077F63F3-3DF4-4041-B3C9-7BAB2BDCA795` to int.

Comment: Thank you .I need to thinking in clam.

Comment: Sure, no problem.